# Random removal of my extensions, Laptop, Windows, Chrome Extensions Ghostery & Adware Plus

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, ghostery

My Chrome extensions are constantly being deleted.

It happens when my laptop is in use and I reload them every time it happens for fear of my data being corrupted. I estimate they delete themselves twice an hour.

I have found forums discussing this as a Chrome fail, I have not found discussions relating this to a virus.

I have tried:

1. Cleaning for virus & malware
2. Reinstalling Chrome
3. Uninstalling suspicious programs
4. Junkware removal tools
5. Syncing my settings while leaving out "extensions"
6. Removed the unwanted extension from Google Chrome
7. Run extensions in developer Mode
8. Remove the related registry entries in HKEY Local Machine & HKEY Current User
9. Removed extension's files using  %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions & deleted all files & emptied reclycle bin.

I frequently run:

1. Stinger 32
2. AdwCleaner
3. Msert
4. CCleaner64
5. McAffee Security Scan Plus

This started after I removed a series of viruses "Buy The App" and "Cut THee Price."  I thought this might have been related to those, but now all scans have come out clean.

The extensions that delete themselves are Ghostery & AdBlock Plus.

I need help please?

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible that despite all those scanners, something has slipped through after cleaning out those previous viruses. One could finally try the [free version of malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/) to see if it catches anything.

Otherwise, at that point, I would reinstall Windows, and be careful in what programs that would be reinstalled.

Comment: I already checked malwarebytes and re-installing windows did nothing.  As mentioned it is a chrome failure